# How to connect JBoss AS 7.1.1 with IIS 7 using Apache ISAPI Redirector 1.2.37

Tags: apache, iis-7.5, jboss7.x, isapi-redirect, jboss-web

I am trying to migrate my web app from JBoss EAP 5 to AS 7.1.1 and I am not able to get the IIS requests redirected to JBoss Web (Tomcat) on Windows 2008 R2 X64.

I have the filter authorized and running in IIS and pointing to the proper DLL and properties files and followed all the instructions I could find to get this working under JB 7 (it  worked under JB 5). I am missing the last step which no one seems to be covering in their posts and answers.

Where do you make the changes to connect JBoss Web to port 8009 used by the AJP 1.3 connector?. Most of the examples refer to updating the connector in the server.xml file in JBOSS_HOME/server/default/Deploy/jbossweb.sar.

I don’t have anything like that under the new JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments folder. Where is JBoss Web configured?

Thank you for any pointers or examples you could supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, the problem was a missing ajp connector that had to be defined in standalone.xml in the web subsystem as follows:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="eStar-Host" native="false">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
    <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
         <ssl/>
    </connector>
    <connector name="ajp13" protocol="AJP/1.3" scheme="http" socket-binding="ajp" redirect-port="8443"/>
    <virtual-server name="eStar-Host" enable-welcome-root="true">
         <alias name="localhost"/>
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```